# Keep "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" IP address the same between restarts

Tags: windows, ip, hyper-v

I have some VM on Hyper-V in my development machine.

Their net adapter is "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" and each VM has a fixed IP `192.168.2.x`

Every time I restart my laptop, I have to edit "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" properties in order to change its IP address to `192.168.2.1` so I can reach my VMs.

#### So the question is:

Is there a way to keep `192.168.2.1` as the "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" IP address between restarts?

Thanks in advance!